# Homogeneous space of elliptic curve in Silverman's AEC

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I have a question in X.3 proposition 3.2 of Silverman's book AEC.

Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve and $C/K$ be a homogeneous space for $E/K$. Fix a point $p_0\in C$ and define a map $\theta: E\rightarrow C$ given by $\theta(P)=p_0+P$, where $+$ means the right action of $E$ over $C$. Then I want to understand why $\theta$ is a morphism defined over $K(p_0)$.

I think a morphism is defined over $K(p_0)$ by definition is invariant under the action of $\text{Gal}(\bar{K}/K(p_0))$. But Silverman proves that $\theta(P)^\sigma=\theta(P^\sigma)$ for all $\sigma\in\text{Gal}(\bar{K}/K)$, I can't see why this imply $\theta$ is defined over $K(p_0)$. Thanks.

Comment: He replaced $K(p_0)$ by $K$. And $\theta(P)^\sigma=\theta(P^\sigma)$ implies that $\theta$ is defined over $K$ only in characteristic $0$ or when $K$ is perfect.

Comment: Dear @reuns My ideal is to prove the map $\theta(\cdot)=p_0+\cdot$ is invariant by $\text{Gal}(\bar{K}/K(p_0))$. This is $\sigma(\theta)=\theta$, or write $\theta(P)^\sigma=\theta(P)$, where the action of $\sigma$ is given by acting on the coefficients of the coordinates formula of $\theta$. But $P$ and $P^\sigma$ appear simultaneously in Silverman's formula, I don't know how to understand his formula.

Comment: I think it is part of the definition of an homogenous space defined over $K$ that the group action $p+Q = f(p,Q)$ is given by a rational function $f\in K(X_1,\ldots,X_n, Y_1,\ldots,Y_m)^n$ so it is obvious that $(p+Q)^\sigma=p^\sigma+Q^\sigma$ for $\sigma\in Gal(\overline{K}/K)$. If $p \in C(L)$ and $\sigma\in Gal(\overline{K}/L)$ then $(p+Q)^\sigma=p+Q^\sigma$.

Comment: @reuns Could I understand in the following way instead of Silverman's proof? The coefficients of the rational function $\theta(Q)=p+Q$ with variable $Q$ lies in the field $K(x_p,y_p)$, thus the morphism is defined over $K(p)=K(x_p,y_p)$.